# How to add a counter for a range of values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, counter

I have an assignment that requires that I create an array of 10 numbers, each a random number between 1 and 100. 
Then I list how many numbers in the array are between 40 and 70. I have the array but I cannot figure out how to add the counter.
Here is what I have so far.

```
package javaapplication10;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author Ravi
 */
public class JavaApplication10 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        //Generates 10 Random Numbers in the range 1 -20
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100 + 1);
        }//end for loop
        System.out.println("Numbers Generated: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

    }
    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. You said you want to "list how many numbers in the array are between 40 and 70", but that doesn't make sense. You either want to **print how many** numbers in the array are between 40 and 70, or you want to **list all numbers** in the array between 40 and 70. which is it?

Comment: Sorry i keep forgetting to be specific when it comes to the code phrases. I want to print how many values in the array are between 40 and 70.

Answer (score 3):

Just have a variable to keep track of the count, then loop through your array checking each element and incrementing the count accordingly.

```
int count = 0;

for (int num : numbers) {
    if (num >= 40 && num <= 70) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);`
```

I assumed you want 40 and 70 included in the range. If you don't, just change the conditions to `>` and `<`. If you also want to print these values, you can just add `System.out.println(num)` inside of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what do you mean, but I thank this is the solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[10];
    int counter = 0;
    // Generates 10 Random Numbers in the range 1 -20
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        if(numbers[i] >= 40 && numbers[i] <= 70)
            counter++;
    }// end for loop
    System.out.println("Numbers Generated: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));           
    System.out.println(counter);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really helpful. I always thought I would need to use a 'for' loop, and never thought to use an 'if' loop.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest code IMHO would be:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.stream(numbers)
    .filter(i -> i >= 40)
    .filter(i -> i <= 70)
    .count());
```

This clearly shows what the conditions are to count the numbers.

But you don't even need the array to do this statistical test:

```
System.out.println(IntStream.generate(() -> 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 100))
    .limit(10)
    .filter(i -> i >= 40)
    .filter(i -> i <= 70)
    .count());
```